# Can I still use the Pork juice dripings after I strain out the pieces of fat storaged in a roaster overnight at room temp?

Tags: pork-chops

Help! I was involved in a Pork chop BBQ yesterday. we did 500 dinners & The guy in charge of it has been doing it for 20 yrs. He makes his own juices in the bottom of a roaster with Lowery's salt & something else in which we put the chops in.Afterwards when it cooled I took a gallon of the juices along with some bits of pork chop fat pieces home in a plastic bucket.Forgot it in the truck over night at around 65 degrees. Brought it strained it & boiled it for 10 mins.Is it still good to freeze & reuse at a later date? I know I should have put in the fridge ...but was offered free beer for the help.And you know guys when offered free beer. Needless to say I killed off a lot of braincells last night. So is it good ya think or not? Any imput is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The quality might be reduced, but your boiling should have taken care of anything that started to grow.  Unless you noticed it being moldy or rancid (which is unlikely to have happened overnight) it shouldn't be a health concern.

Comment: ouch--when in doubt, throw it out